# How to fix indentation of C++ methods with ref-qualifiers?

Tags: indentation, c++

Emacs in its default configuration seems to have trouble indenting C++ methods with reference qualifiers (& and &&). For example:

```cpp
struct foo {
    void a_method() && {
                        std::cout << "rvalue ref\n";
    }

    void a_method() const& {
                            std::cout << "lvalue const ref\n";
    }

    void this_gets_properly_indented() const {
        std::cout << "without a ref-qualifier\n";
    }

    auto this_too() && -> void {
        std::cout << "rvalue ref; '->' notation\n";
    }
};
```

One workaround I have found is to use the `->` syntax for return types, but this breaks too if the return type is a reference. Can this behaviour be somehow configured?

Comment: Your example does work for me with Emacs 26.1, and `c-indentation-style`  `"visual"`.

Comment: @Tobias Ha! Calling `(c-set-style "visual")` actually fixed it. I do have 26.1 too, and `c-indentation-style` was "gnu" by default. I can't find any documentation on this "visual" style though. It's not in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Built_002din-Styles.html#Built_002din-Styles). =/

Comment: "linux", "bsd" and "java" styles also seem to give good results.

Comment: I think, I have localized it further. In "gnu" style there is a `brace-list-intro` item in `c-offsets-alist`, which is set to `c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren`. When I set it to `+` instead it seems to fix the problem. But, as I understand it, `brace-list-intro` is used for initializer lists, not code blocks. :| It definitely looks like an error.

Comment: `cc-mode` is built-in. Your problem is not listed in [cc-mode limitations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Limitations-and-Known-Bugs.html) and a search for [indent AND ref AND qualifier](https://sourceforge.net/p/cc-mode/mailman/search/?q=indent+AND+ref+AND+qualifier&mail_list=all) in the cc-mode-help mailing list does not give relevant results. If you think you found a bug please report it either with `M-x report-emacs-bug` or at `bug-cc-mode@gnu.org`. Thanks for making Emacs better.

Comment: Fixed [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=35194). The patch will probably be in Emacs 27.